# rand() not produce random [c]

Tags: c, random

I was asked to write a program that produces a 2d array of random numbers. My code produces strange results. Regardless of the size of the matrix it produces a "reverse diagonal matrix" (not sure what else to call it). I was to understand that rand() produces a pseudorandom number between 0 and RAND_MAX but somehow the results are dependent on the size of my matrix, I am unsure how this behavior could happen.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAT_SIZE 5

void main (void)
{

srand(time(0));

unsigned char * ptr = malloc(MAT_SIZE*MAT_SIZE);
unsigned char i, j;

for(i = 0; i < MAT_SIZE; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < MAT_SIZE ; j ++)
    {

        *(ptr + i + j ) = rand();
    }
}
 for(i = 0; i < MAT_SIZE ; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < MAT_SIZE ; j ++)
    {
        printf("%5d", *(ptr + i + j));
    }
    printf("\n");
}
    free(ptr);
}
```

Output for 3*3

```
142  141   11
141   11  230
11   230   28
```

Output for 5*5

```
232  157   62  131  245
157   62  131  245   54
 62  131  245   54  138
131  245   54  138  246
245   54  138  246  108
```

Even a pseudorandom number shouldn't behave differently based on how it is used. Is there something I'm not understanding about the program that forces these results?

Comment: Your code would be much simpler if, instead of allocating a block of memory and trying to map a matrix into it, you simply declared and used a matrix directly: i.e. `int matrix[MAT_SIZE][MAT_SIZE];`

Comment: *(ptr + i + j )   ==>   *(p[i]+j)

Comment: Nope gangadhar, that's a segfault. `p[i]` is a char, not a pointer.

Comment: @Ferruccio, you should have elaborated that into an answer. Unfortunately, there is still a lot of code around that sells such "emulation" of 2D arrays to beginners instead of teaching them the right thing from the start.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is not with the random numbers that are generated but with how you are saving them in your matrix. To access element `(j, i)` you do not want

```
*(ptr + i + j )
```

but

```
*(ptr + MAT_SIZE * i + j )
```

Answer (score 2):

You are only accessing the first `i+j` members of the array, and looping over the same indices repeatedly.  Instead of:

`*(ptr + i + j )`

Try

`*(ptr + i * MAT_SIZE + j )`

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can dynamically allocate a 2D array as follows:

```
unsigned char (*ptr)[MAT_SIZE] = malloc( MAT_SIZE * sizeof *ptr );
...
ptr[i][j] = rand();
...
free( ptr );
```

Makes life a little simpler.  This way you can use normal 2D array indexing instead of having to map `i` and `j` to a single dimension.

Nits:

Unless your compiler documentation *explicitly* lists `void main()` as a valid signature for `main`, use `int main( void )` instead.  I know you've seen thousands of examples of `void main()` in books and on line, but just because the compiler doesn't complain about it doesn't mean it isn't wrong.

`rand()` returns `int`, which will not fit into an `unsigned char`.  Overflow on unsigned types is well-defined, but even so, you may want to explicitly map your `rand` result onto the range [0..255].